# Heroku routing of HTTP PATCH requests

Tags: heroku

I am having trouble sending HTTP PATCH requests to my application. Here is the log I see:

```
Mar 22 20:34:40 canvs heroku/router:  at=info method=METHOD_OTHER path="/v2/art/edit/132/" host=canvs.herokuapp.com request_id=9f4eafe5-5624-45fb-b7d2 fwd="010.173.106.34" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=109ms status=405 bytes=185
```

Somehow the PATCH verb seems to be replaced by METHOD_OTHER.

This has suddenly started happening so I am pretty confident that its not something I have changed.

Also btw, the same request works with a HTTPS connection.

Answer (score 1):

`PATCH` is not (yet) a HTTP standard (but rather a [proposed standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789)), and seems to not be as widely supported as other HTTP methods/verbs.

For example, I have experienced that some versions of Squid (maybe even the latest, haven't tested) replace `PATCH` with `METHOD_OTHER`.

You could try switching to `PUT`, which seems to be more widely supported.